# Stack support via the Swiper module

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there a module or someone will suggest how to swipe it to the right to not remove the card from the stack in Swiper like Tinder?

In the libraries that I found in the network is like this:

```
initialStack():
A B C D E

swipeRight():
B C D E

swipeRight():
C D E

swipeLeft():
D E

swipeLeft():
E

swipeRight():
empty stack
```

What I need:

```
initialStack():
A B C D E

swipeRight(index = 2):
B C A D E

swipeLeft():
C A D E

swipeRight(index = 3):
A D E C

swipeLeft():
D E C
```

Anyone have any advice?

In a situation where I would swipe only to the right, I rewind the cards indefinitely only in a different order (due to the fact that I give the index where it should be moved)